# CSS3 - Adding dynamic content triggers animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have animation defined in CSS3 for specific class which runs only one time when that class is added to a element. The problem is when I add dynamic content to their parent the animation runs for one more time. Everytime, content is added the animation triggers. A list element which is to be animated is automatically added to `ul` and it animates one time (expected behaviour) whereas, the non-animable elements are added on JS Event.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="m"><div class="animable"></div></li>
    <li class="m"><div class="animable animateNow"></div></li>
</ul>
```

When JS event occurs, a list element is added dynamically.

```
<ul>
    <li class="m"><div class="animable"></div></li>
    <li class="m"><div class="animable animateNow"></div></li>
    <li class="m"><div class="animable"></div></li> // <- Sir! I am innocent. I am newly added by JS. IDK, what is happening :/
</ul>
```

and the moment it is appended , the animable div triggers its animation for one more time and so on for each added element.

Is this a bug ? How can I prevent it? I am using pure JS.

CSS:

```
.animable {
    position:absolute;

    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    background:#ecf7d2;
}
.animateNow {
    opacity:0;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: animTrans;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: animTrans;
}
```

[image: The Big Image]

Comment: It's hard to say without a fiddle.

Comment: @Itay It's hard for me also because the things are using Websocket but let me try.

Comment: When is the `.animateNow` class added to an element?

Comment: @Itay See man the `animatedNow` elements are added by websocket. It is new message from other person which background is to be animated from light yellow to 100% transparent.

Comment: And are you sure this class isn't being added to those unwanted animated items?

Comment: @Itay Yeah! Let me add picture describing the behaviour.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36982/discussion-between-muhammad-talha-akbar-and-itay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On our discussion in the chat, you showed the code that adds the items:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("messages").getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
elem.innerHTML += msg.data;
```

Your problem is that you're changing the innerHTML every time, which makes the entire content of the list to render again and again...

You should create a DOM element and use [Node.appendChild(*child*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) instead.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("messages").getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

var item = document.createElement('LI');
item.outerHTML = msg.data;

elem.appendChild(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use preventdefault function i think but without seeing the js part or in fiddle  what u doing its hard to suggest share JS part too